# How to create a Drawer navigation in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a Stack navigation, A Drawer navigation and a Bottom Tab navigation. My Stack navigation and Bottom Tab navigation is working fine, but Can't make the Drawer Navigation. Could you tell me what I am missing here? It seems to me Drawer navigation and Tab navigation has a conflict in my code...but can't find why ??? Please help.

**My App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView,DrawerItemList,DrawerItem, } from '@react-navigation/drawer';  
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import FeedScreen from './src/screens/FeedScreen';
import Cards from './src/screens/CardScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
import Message from './src/screens/MessagesScreen';



function DetailsScreen() {
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Details!</Text>
</View>
 );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
 return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Settings screen</Text>
  <Button
    title="Go to Cards"
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cards')}
   />
 </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
return (
<HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
  <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}  />
  <HomeStack.Screen name="FeedScreen" component={FeedScreen} />
  <HomeStack.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
 );
}

const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function SettingsStackScreen() {
return (
<SettingsStack.Navigator>
  <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  <SettingsStack.Screen name="Cards" component={Cards} />
</SettingsStack.Navigator>
);
}

const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function ProfileStackScreen(){
 return (
  <ProfileStack.Navigator>
   <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}/>
   {/* <ProfileStack.Screen name="Cards" component={Cards}/> */}
 </ProfileStack.Navigator>
 )
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function MyDrawer() {
 return (
  <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ drawerPosition: 'left' }}>
   <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
   <Drawer.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>   
  );
 }

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
     <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />        
    </Tab.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have found the solutions, I just entered tab navigation into drawer navigation and now it's working fine

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
 useAnimatedStyle,
  Easing,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView,
DrawerItemList,
 DrawerItem, } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

 import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
 import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
 import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
 import FeedScreen from './src/screens/FeedScreen';
 import Cards from './src/screens/CardScreen';
 import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
 import Message from './src/screens/MessagesScreen';

 const Stack   = createNativeStackNavigator();
 const Tab     = createBottomTabNavigator();
 const Drawer  = createDrawerNavigator();

 function Tabs() {
  return (
   <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen  name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}  />
   <Tab.Screen  name="Profile"  component={ProfileScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}   />
   <Tab.Screen  name="Message"  component={Message} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
   </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function StackNavigator() {
  return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
 </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

 export default function App() {
 return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Stack">
    <Drawer.Screen  name="Tabs" component={Tabs}  />        
  </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```